# Update clamav offline

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

The host OS Windows 10 and it is running VirtualBox 6.1.12.

**Guest OS 1 (VM 1)**: Ubuntu 16.04 **headless server**: Network Setting: Adapter 1 attached to Bridged : Network Setting: Adapter 2 attached to Internal network

**Guest OS 2 (VM 2)**: Ubuntu 16.04 **headless server**: Network Setting: Adapter 1 attached to Internal Network

Installed clamav and squid in both my vm.

Disclaimer: I am reading on this [guide](https://rasyid.net/2009/02/10/update-clam-anti-virus-definition-offline/) , but there are some things i still not sure how to go about doing it

Issue:

1. How to download the latest version on my vm1
2. after downloading the file, how do I transfer it from my vm1 to vm2

full disclosure: this is my first time doing this, I do not have any prior knowledge. I will appreciate any advice given on this matter, please forgive if my question is not clear

Comment: How you download is up to you. Personally I'd use `wget` to download, and then `scp` to copy between machines, however this will only work if you've setup VMs to accept this; the setup is done on the HOST OS which is windows 10 as you describe it, so off-topic on this site.  *Most issues in VMs in my experience are on the setup, which is done on the host*

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, basically the host is vm1, not window 10. so i just type wget http://www.clamav.org/download/cvd      ??

Comment: I just started linux, too used to using windows

Comment: By host I mean the box that is running the VMs, you've reported both VM1 and VM2 are guests, so by host I mean the infrastructure that is running those guests.  If your host is setup correctly, I'd use `wget` to download, and `scp` to copy files between hosts.  (If that doesn't work, I'd look for a misconfugration in the virtualbox config on windows 10 box)

Comment: it is setup properly, i ping google and have receive package, so that means my vm1 is connected to real internet

Comment: however when i wget http://www.clamav.org/download/cvd i have encounter 403 forbidden, i am on root

Comment: Please add additional detail to your question, and provide command & output, as it's easier to understand. If you open your browser and look, you'll note that it's not a Ubuntu issue but a cloudflare & external issue that will impact any attempt from any OS attempting download..  Use general principles in problem solving

Comment: after further research, the guide link is dead. so i switch to curl -O http://database.clamav.net/main.cvd